Convert regex with set of numbers to vector of strings
I have a vector of regular expressions that include a set/range of numbers. I want to convert each expression into a vector of strings that explicitly spells out each match. For instance, given x I want the result below. I also have tried the following but couldn't really get it to work. Is there a way to achieve what I want?
data
x <- c("N17[0-3]", "438[46]", "I6[02-45]1", "V[1-3]71")

want
"N170", "N171", "N172", "N173", "4384", "4386", "I601", "I621", "I631", "I641", "I651", "V171", "V271", "V371"

tried
x_split <- strsplit(x, "")
lapply(x_split, function(y) {
  bracket1_idx <- which(y == "[")
  bracket2_idx <- which(y == "]")
  num1 <- y[bracket1_idx+1]
  num2 <- y[bracket2_idx-1]
  substr1 <- y[1:bracket1_idx-1] |> paste0(collapse="")
  
  if(bracket2_idx == length(y)) paste0(substr1, seq(num1, num2))
  else {
    substr2 <- y[(bracket2_idx+1):length(y)] |> paste0(collapse="")
    paste0(substr1, seq(num1, num2), substr2)
  }
})


First replace digit, minus, digit with the sequence of digits in the gsubfn line and then in the next line generate a list of vectors and finally unlist that.
library(gsubfn)

x |>
  gsubfn("(\\d)-(\\d)", ~ paste(seq(x, y), collapse = ""), x = _) |>
  strapply("(.*)\\[(\\d*)\\](.*)", ~ paste0(x, strsplit(y, "")[[1]], z)) |>
  unlist()

##  [1] "N170" "N171" "N172" "N173" "4384" "4386" "I601" "I621" "I631" "I641" "I651" "V171"
## [13] "V271" "V371"


There's a Python package exrex which does precisely what you're describing:

Exrex is a command line tool and python module that generates all - or random - matching strings to a given regular expression and more.

Perhaps this is lazy, or if you like you can say it's more robust and possibly better able to handle edge cases than rolling your own solution, but I would just install that from a terminal:
# Assuming Python is already installed
pip install exrex

Then you can interface with the command line tool from R:
exrex <- function(l) {
    lapply(l, \(x) processx::run("exrex", x))
}

# [[1]]
# [1] "N170" "N171" "N172" "N173"

# [[2]]
# [1] "4384" "4386"

# [[3]]
# [1] "I601" "I621" "I631" "I641" "I651"

# [[4]]
# [1] "V171" "V271" "V371"

You can unlist() the return value if you like.
I prefer processx as it will escape the strings properly and handle spaces. See Store result of system call in R object for a comparison with system() and system2(). If you don't have spaces and don't want an additional package you could do it this way:
exrex <- function(l) {
    lapply(
        l,
        \(x) system2("exrex", args = shQuote(x), stdout = TRUE)
    )
}

exrex(x)
# same output

shQuote() means strings containing quotes like "N17\"[0-4]" will be properly escaped. However, even with shQuote() neither system() nor system2() will properly handle strings with spaces.

Here's an approach using base R:
patterns <- regmatches(x, regexpr("\\[.*\\]", x))
replacements <- sapply(patterns, \(v) grep(v, 0:9, value = TRUE)) 

mapply(sub,
       rep(patterns, lengths(replacements)),
       unlist(replacements),
       rep(x, lengths(replacements)),
       fixed = TRUE,
       USE.NAMES = FALSE)

 [1] "N170" "N171" "N172" "N173" "4384" "4386" "I601" "I621" "I631" "I641" "I651" "V171" "V271"
[14] "V371"

